# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: ros, python2.7, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to fix this issue.
I followed this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=7RH4WF1RBwg&feature=youtu.be&fbclid=IwAR0yYH6CEG-IPwgPmM3r-B-bWNo1VABuU7Yrz7htAOmax57z6aBhVdzHLXg)

This full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy

from std_msgs.msg import String


rate1 = 30
rate2 = 1
msg1 = "30 hz"
msg2 = "1 hz"

def callbsck1(event):
  pub_1.publish(msg1)

def callbsck2(event):
  pub_2.publish(msg2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  rospy.init_node('async_publish')
  pub_1 = rospy.Publisher ('topic1', String, queue_size=10)
  pub_2 = rospy.Publisher('topic2', String, queue_size=10)
  rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1/rate1), callbsck1)
  rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1 / rate2), callbsck2)
  rospy.spin()
```

This error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/timer.py", line 221, in run
    r = Rate(1.0 / self._period.to_sec(), reset=self._reset)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369059/zerodivisionerror:-float-division-by-zero/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2021-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Python 2 treats the division operator `/` differently, depending on the operands. If both operands are integers (this is what you have here with `1` and `30`) it is an integer division (and float division, if one of the operands is a float).

Integer division only returns the "integer" part, the fractional part is discarded. Thus, you'll end up with 1/30=0.

(In Python 3, `/` is always float division. `//` is integer division)

There are multiple ways to fix this:

1. make at least one of the operands a float by adding a dot, i.e. `1.0`, `30.0` or even `1.` or `30.`
2. cast one of the operands explicitly to float: `float(1)`, `float(30)`
3. "activate" the Python 3 behavior of having `/` always as float division using a future import

   ```
    from __future__ import division
   ```

   (Note that  `__future__` imports have to come before any other import statement)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2021-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2021-01-07**:
Thanks, it is fine now